# Dataflow writing to Datastore: "Message: datastore transaction or write too big."

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm just starting with Dataflow / Apache Beam.
I wrote a Dataflow pipeline in Python to import a big catalog of products (> 50K products, stored inside a JSON file) into Datastore.
The pipeline runs fine on my local machine (DirectRunner) but fails on the DataflowRunner with the following error message:

```
RPCError: datastore call commit [while running 'write to datastore/Write Mutation to Datastore'] failed: Error code: INVALID_ARGUMENT. Message: datastore transaction or write too big.
```

My guess would be that Datastore can't handle the write rate of the pipeline, but I'm not sure on how I can throttle down the writing in the Dataflow pipeline.

I'm using the WriteToDatastore transform to write to DataStore:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore
```

My pipeline looks like this:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
(p  # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
 | 'read from json' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input, coder=JsonCoder())
 | 'create entity' >> beam.Map(
     EntityWrapper(known_args.namespace, known_args.kind,
                   known_args.ancestor).make_entity)
 | 'write to datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(known_args.dataset))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like a write rate issue. That error message means a mutation was above system limits. Causes can include:

- Exceeding 500 entities in a single transaction
- Exceeding 10MiB in a single transaction
- Exceeding 1MiB in a single entity
- Exceeding 2MiB total composite index size for an entity

You can read more about Cloud Datastore system limits in our [Limits documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dan.
Strange thing is that it doesn't fail at all when using the DirectRunner.
Also, my entities are small (1 key & 2 properties, all very small), and I don't use any transaction capabilities (I don't believe the WriteToDatastore use any transaction by default).
Same for the indexes ...

Is there an easy way to identify the entity that triggers the Exception ?

Else, I'm thinking in implementing the same pipeline in Java to see  if my problem goes away ...

Comment: Hi Dan.

I tried switching to Java, but I'm running into the same issue.

Strange thing is that sometimes the pipeline runs successfully, and sometimes it will just fail with this error message.

I believe this is a write rate issue, that happens when writing to Datastore Kinds that have indexes.

I'm looking for a way to control the write rate to DataStore, but can't find anything online.

Any clue ?